# Why code not working while replacing the text in file

Tags: python

I have a file called `test.txt`.

I need to convert one string in the file which matches the dictionary.

`test.txt`:

```
abc
asd
ds
{{  PRODUCT CATEGORY  }}
fdsavfacxvasdvvc
dfvssfzxvdfvzd
```

Code is below:

```
data = {'PRODUCT CATEGORY':'Customer'}
all_files = ['test.txt']
out_files = ['ut.txt']
read_dict = {}
for file in all_files:
    with open(file,'r') as read_file:
        lines = read_file.readlines()
        read_dict[file] = lines
for in_f, out_f in zip(all_files, out_files):
    with open(in_f,'r') as read_file:
        lines = read_file.readlines()
    with open(out_f,'w+') as write_file:        
        for line in lines:
            updated_line = []
            for word in line.split():
                if word in data:
                    updated_line.append(data[word])
                else:
                    updated_line.append(word)
            write_file.writelines(" ".join(updated_line))                            
            print (" ".join(updated_line))
```

There is a space at the end and at the beginning  `PRODUCT CATEGORY`

Expected output:

```
abc
asd
ds
Customer
fdsavfacxvasdvvc
dfvssfzxvdfvzd
```

Comment: What does "not working" mean, exactly?  I have no idea what sort of problem I should be looking for.

Comment: @jasonharper  printed the expected out also

Comment: You are splitting on words, so no single word can match the key in `data` which is two words. A lot of this code seems unnecessary anyway; always try to reduce your question to a [mre].

Comment: @tripleee i have given sample input, output, and my code

Comment: And I have explained why it doesn't work; isn't that why you ask? But it would be easier to see what's wrong if 70% of the code wasn't unrelated to your problem.

Comment: @aysh Please try the edited code

Comment: There are *two* spaces on each side inside the braces in `{{  PRODUCT CATEGORY  }}`, is that an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
import re
data = {'PRODUCT CATEGORY':'Customer'}
all_files = ['test.txt']
out_files = ['ut.txt']

for in_f, out_f in zip(all_files, out_files):
    with open(in_f,'r') as read_file:
        text = read_file.read()
        for word, replace_with in data.items():
            text = re.sub(r'\{+ *'+ word + r' *\}+', replace_with, text)
        open(out_f,'w+').write(text)
```

Comment: SyntaxError: f-string expression part cannot include a backslash

Comment: The fix is easy *per se;* just use `{{` instead of `\{` and similarly a double closing curly brace instead of a backslashed one. But using an f-string to build a regex is kind of iffy anyway; the remaining curlies need to be escaped from the regex engine, too. Perhaps better to just say `r'\{+ +%s +\}+' % word`

Comment: @tripleee still not working, new file is not working

Comment: @aysh does above code work !? Tell me if still you are facing some issue

Comment: its working file, for testing if i remove {{PRODUCT CATEGORY}}  beginning and trailing space. then its failing

Comment: I have edited the code to acomodate that change. Please try the edited code

Answer (score 1):

You are splitting by white space, and you have a white space in "Product category" so it never finds an exact match for the word. You can see this if you add a `print(word)` after the `for word in line.split()` line

A way to solve this is by replacing `Product category` with `Product_Category` in data and in your test.txt file.

Also, you are missing the new line carry after writting each line to the output file, you should replace:

```
    write_file.writelines(" ".join(updated_line))
```

with

```
    write_file.writelines(" ".join(updated_line)+"\n")
```

With both these issues solved you get the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

You can't loop over individual words on the input line because that prevents you from finding a dictionary key which consists of more than one word, like the one you have in your example.

Here is a simple refactoring which prints to standard output just so you can see what you are doing.

```py
data = {'PRODUCT CATEGORY':'Customer'}
all_files = ['test.txt']

for file in all_files:
    with open(file,'r') as read_file:
      for line in read_file:
        for keyword in data:
          token = '{{ %s }}' % keyword
          if token in line:
            line = line.replace(token, data[keyword])
        print(line, end='')
```

The `end=''` is necessary because `line` already contains a newline, but `print` wants to supply one of its own; if you `write` to a file instead of `print`, you can avoid this particular quirk. (But often, a better design for reusability is to just print to standard output, and let the caller decide what to do with the output.)

It is unclear why you had a separate `read_dict` for the lines in the input file or why you read the file twice, so I removed those parts.

Looping over a file a line at a time avoids reading the entire file into memory, so if you don't care what's on the previous or the next lines, this is usually a good idea, and scales to much bigger files (you only need to keep one line in memory at a time -- let's hope that one *line* is not several gigabytes).

Here is a demo (I took the liberty to use just one space in `{{ PRODUCT CATEGORY }}` and fix the spelling of "customer"): https://repl.it/repls/DarkredMindlessPackagedsoftware#main.py